# Ephedrine or pseudoephedrine indirectly central alpha2 mimetic?

Tags: human-biology, physiology, pharmacology

I started to think this problem by first thinking if the alpha2 mimetism is possible in either case. 
It seems to be indirectly in either one. 
Ephedrine seems to have more prominent effect in CNS. 
So I propose that Ephedrine has indirect central alpha2 mimetic effect.

**Is ephedrine central alpha2 mimetic?** 
I think one evidence about that would be if there is a alpha2 receptor which is activated by ephedrine somehow indirectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anongoodnurse provide an excellent comment in other discussion about how to search PubChem.

Ephedrine is not alpha2 mimetic. 
Pseudoephedrine is alpha2 mimetic, [source](http://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/pseudoephedrine#section=DrugBank-Interactions):

[image]